# Scope property not released for ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checklist-model

Below is a simple example of my problem that seems to be created by the AngularJS "checklist-model" module.  When I set my oData = undefined it should hide the div with ng-show, but for some strange reason it takes two button clicks to set oData.  The oData.counties property although undefined after the first button click still remains around until a second button click.  I assume this has to do with checklist having a local copy the oData.counties in its scope but that is only a guess.  And I can only assume there is a trick to releasing it on the first attempt.  Any help would be very welcome.

Plunker now working, thanks Lex... it is: [myPlunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6BBX0qiqWKovVqiQ2ykG?p=preview)

Example HTML

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as TestController">

    <button ng-model="showHide" ng-click="TestController.pause()">TEST</button>

    <div ng-show="TestController.oData">
        <div ng-repeat="county in Counties">

            <input type="checkbox"
                   checklist-model="TestController.oData.counties"
                   checklist-value="county.countyno" />

            {{county.countyno}} {{county.countyname}}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example Controller:

```
'use strict';

app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    var _this = this; // the controller
    _this.name = "TestController";
    _this.oData = {
        "name": "harvey mushman",
        "counties": ["19", "21"]
    };

    $scope.Counties = [
        { countyname: "Lassen", countyno: 18 },
        { countyname: "Los Angeles", countyno: 19 },
        { countyname: "Madera", countyno: 20 },
        { countyname: "Marin", countyno: 21 }
    ]

    this.pause = function () {
        // debugger;
        console.log(_this.oData);
        _this.oData = undefined;
        console.log(_this.oData);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I don't see any problems in your code. Remove ng-model from the button, maybe it makes an error.

Comment: It must have something to do with the fact that using `ng-show` just hides it so everything is still in the DOM because if you use `ng-if` instead I believe a single click of the button will produce the desired behavior. Somehow `checklist-model` is recreating the `countries` property of `TestController.oData` the first time the button is clicked. You can verify this because the second time you click the button your `console.log()` outputs an object with a `countries` property.

Comment: As for your Plunker, there were several issues. I forked a corrected version [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/pvehRJZq0Adu7EOSa7XG?p=preview).

Comment: It is checklist-model's problem.

Comment: File an issue on GitHub with the Author of the Directive -- [GitHub vitalets/checklist-model Issues](https://github.com/vitalets/checklist-model/issues). Frankly I would avoid using that directive as it is not properly integrated with the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

Comment: georgeawg, I agree with you and the directions on his GitHub offering is to post issues here.  The idea of using ng-if and testing two values as suggested above by Lex fork, just seems like a patch to an underlying problem in the directive.  Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Lex - thank you for creating a fork of my posting.  You are correct, I made several dumb mistakes that you so nicely fixed.  I'm still trying to learn my way around posting here.  As far as your solution, I don't agree with your fix.  There is no reason that I'm aware of that the author should be recreating or creating a private scope to the check list data.  I'm concerned that as I use the directive more and more, this problem will return to bite me worse.  Again, thank you very much for your time and considerations...!